# TinyMCE image customization

Tags: tinymce, customization

How can I customize *TinyMCE* so that I'll be able to choose a css class for a specific image?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [style_formats setting of tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3astyle_formats) to use the style plugin with classes of your own (using content_css setting too)

```
// Style formats
style_formats: [{
    title: 'Styles'
}, {
    title: 'Absatz 1',
    block: 'p',
    classes: 'absatz1',
    exact: true
}, {
    title: 'Absatz 2',
    block: 'p',
    classes: 'absatz2',
    exact: true
},
```